# Questions about Simplex method - How should I devide?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I have made a simplex method algorithm in C language and I have some questions about it.

Assume that we have this objective function.
$$max: z = c^T x$$
At the subject to:
$$Ax <= b \\ x >= 0$$

Then we create our tableau matrix $T$.

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
A & I & 0 & b\\ 
-c^T & 0 & 1 & z
\end{bmatrix}$$

$z = 0$ to begin with and the $I$ is the identity matrix. The last row is one single vector row.

My procedure is easy!

- Step 1:
  I check the SMALLEST negative value in **ONLY** $-c^T$. If all the elements in vector **ONLY** $-c^T$ are $> 0$ then I quit my algorithm, else, I remember what index the smallest negative value have its position. Assume it calls $indexColumn$
- Step 2:
  I take the first row of **ONLY** $A$ at the column $indexColumn$ and divide it with the first row of vector **ONLY** $b$. I loop the whole rows in **ONLY** $A$ and **ONLY** $b$ and I check which value will be come smallest. Don't care about the $I$ matrix and the $z$ value.

  $$value = b(i) /A(i, indexColumn)$$
- Step 3:
  When I find the smallest value on $indexRow$ (I call it like that), then I make sure that the the value in $A(indexRow, indexColum)$ will be 1 and the rest of $A(:, indexColumn)$ will be 0.

By doing that, I do some row operations.

$$\frac{1}{\text{smallest value}}*R_{indexRow} -> R_{indexRow}$$

And the rest
$$
-\frac{1}{A(\text{i, indexColum})}*R_{indexRow} + R_i-> R_{i}
$$

Where $i \neq indexRow$

I wrote some C code for that, but I have some issues with it and I wonder if my steps are correct?

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack/blob/master/EmbeddedLapack/src/LinearAlgebra/linprog.c

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @copper.hat If I'm thinking correct in the algorithm. Should I divide $z$ too?

Comment: The dimension of $c^T$ and the column dimension of $A$ may be inconsistent. How can you construct the $T$ matrix properly?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable I have solved this problem  :) try the code

Comment: Okay, you just assume the dimensions to be consistent :P

Comment: @unbelieveTable you can select the dimensions. Just look at the examples.